# Sending a huge data [object-Serialized] from Client to Server in wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

When Serialized string is sent from wcf client to wcf service
Following Exception occurs:
Communication Exception :

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to `http://localhost:#####/SeriveName.svc`. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Note : object that is serialized in turn contains properties that are serialized [Heirarchical serialization]

Comment: What does the server log says?

Comment: How big is this serialized string?

Comment: @ MiMo : How to check server logs..     @ jmrnet : if saved in note pad around 30 mb but in upcomping future it may take much more than that

Comment: Have you tried sending a smaller request to the server to see if it is actually the size of the message that is the issue?